# Python Discord bot error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am am making a discord bot in python.

In the output it says that I have 4 errors.

I do not understand why.

I have installed discord.py and I am using Python 3.5.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Errors:

```
E0611:No name 'exe' in module 'discord'    
E0602:Undefined variable 'message'  
E0401:Unable to import 'discord.exe.commands'  
E0602:Undefined variable 'message'
```

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.exe.commands import Bot 
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is sailing on the seven seas")

@client.event
async def on_message(maker):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:")


client.run("1NDE2--CHANGED--L24CMo"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error: You imported `discord.exe`; its called `discord.ext`

Second error: You assigned the `message` argument to the name `maker` in the `on_message` declaration. Change it to `on_message(message)` to get the variable